# Find a sequence $a$ so that $a_n = s \Delta a_n $.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Let $s$ be a real number $ s \ne 0 $. Find a sequence  $a$ so that $a_n = s \Delta a_n $ and $a_0 = 1$.

Any help with this question will be great. This is my first time doing recurrence relations and I am very confused.

Comment: please define $\Delta a_n$. I bet it is $a_n-a_{n-1}$.

Comment: $\Delta a_n = a_{n+1} - a_n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With you definition, what is required is
$$
a_n = sa_{n+1}-sa_n\iff a_{n+1} = \frac{s+1}s a_n
$$
this is the definition of a geometric sequence.

The general solution has the form
$$
a_n = A \left[ \frac{s+1}s \right]^n
$$and with $1=a_0 = A$ you find that

$$
a_n = \left[ \frac{s+1}s \right]^n
$$

---

You have proved that IF $u$ was a solution it had the required form.

You then have to check that if you define $u$ this way, the relation holds.
You see that you need the condition $s\neq 0$. Then $u$ is defined and:

$$
s\Delta a_n = sa_{n+1}-sa_n
= sa_n \left[ \frac{s+1}s -1\right] 
= sa_n \frac{1}s = a_n
$$